# Position representation of the parameter derivative of an eigenstate

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Let a eigenstate of a hamiltonian depend on a parameter $\lambda$, such that

$$\hat{H}_{(\lambda )}\left| n_{(\lambda )} \right> = E_{n \,(\lambda )} \left| n_{(\lambda )} \right> $$

Is it possible to write

$$\left< x \right| \frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda} \left. n_{(\lambda )} \right> = \frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda} \left< x \right. \left| n_{(\lambda )} \right>$$

Even if $\lambda$ is time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Note that it is not relevant that $|n(\lambda)\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian. Whenever you have a parameter-dependent state $|\psi(\lambda)\rangle$ (i.e., a function $\lambda \mapsto |\psi(\lambda)\rangle$) and any fixed state $|\varphi\rangle$, then
$$ \langle \varphi | \partial_\lambda | \psi(\lambda)\rangle = \partial_\lambda \langle \varphi | \psi(\lambda) \rangle $$
due to the linearity of the inner product $\langle \cdot | \cdot \rangle$.